# iOS 9 Webview only loading HTML

Tags: ios, ios9

So I updated to iOS 9 and saw that webview was just a blank screen on my app. I read up on it and learned about ATS. I saw the quick solution of just switching NSAllowsArbitraryLoads to true but I don't want to risk rejection on the Apple store. All I'm trying to do is load the webpage of the app. I have added the domain to the list of NSExceptionDomains on Info.plist. So now it loads but the problem is it's the html only. It doesn't load any of the CSS or images. This is what is under the dict for the page domain.

```
<key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
<true/>
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
<true/>
<key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
<string>1.0</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could ignore all that plist stuff and try a `SFSafariViewController` instead of the UIWebViewController.

```
Class class = NSClassFromString(@"SFSafariViewController");
if(class)
{
    SFSafariViewController *webController = [[SFSafariViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
    ...
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{
        }];
}
else
{
    //Use the standard webview controller
}
```

That Controller's view was built to ignore the new TLS requirements.  IT worked for my project, hopefully it's close enough to your needs to help too.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yea I was trying to see if I could avoid using a SFSafariViewController so that the webpage would still feel part of the app in terms of the header keeping the look of the app. But yea the more I research the more it seems I do have to use SFSafariViewController. Thanks for your help